# Two TextViews per row in Android ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have an expandable text view within my app. I can get it to display all the information in one text view, but I really want one of the lines of text to be bold to stand out, so I figured the best way for me to do this would be using a second textview, and then setting it within that. I've looked at loads of examples, but I can't quite figure out how to put it in.
MainActivity -

```
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView experienceExpList;
List<String> experienceHeaders;
HashMap<String, List<String>> experienceChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xtra_adventures);

    experienceExpList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp); //call list view
    prepareListData(); //get the list data function

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, experienceHeaders, experienceChild); //creates list adapter
    experienceExpList.setAdapter(listAdapter); //set list adapter

    //eventually onclick listener to purchase experience
}

private void prepareListData() {
    experienceHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    experienceChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    experienceHeaders.add("Experiences");
    List<String> experiences = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        JSONArray mainNode = new JSONArray(loadJSONFromAsset()); // call the connection to json


        if(mainNode != null) //puts the values into an array
        {
            for(int i=0;i<mainNode.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject eachObject = mainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                String type = eachObject.getString("type");

                if(type.equals("Experience"))
                {
                    String name = eachObject.getString("name");
                    String price = eachObject.getString("price");
                    String description = eachObject.getString("description");

                    String experience = (name + "\n" + price + "\n" + description);

                    experiences.add(experience);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    experienceChild.put(experienceHeaders.get(0), experiences); // Header, Child data
}
```

Along with this, I have my adapter, which has the get child view method

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    TextView txtListChild2 = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem2);

    txtListChild.setText(childText); //want name here
    txtListChild2.setText( ); //price and description here
    return convertView;
}
```

Within my list item (child) xml layout, I have a text view lvlListItem, but what I really want to do, is set a second one, which displays just the name `String name = eachObject.getString("name");` got in the MainActivity.java.

Any help as to how to set a second textview would be appreciated, as I can't seem to figure how to join it up with what I have.

list item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />
```

Comment: Add another `TextView` to `exp_list_item.xml`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I just can't figure how to connect it to the rest and assign the one value I want to it.

Comment: You haven't explained that well since you don't show an attempt at what you want. It's hard to understand *exactly* where you are stuck

Comment: added in the layout with the second text view and added into childview

Comment: Or simply use `txtListChild.setText(HTML.fromHtml(childText + " <b>" + price + "</b>"));` where price is the number or text is the text you want to be bold.

Answer (score 0):

Add another text view to your layout file `exp_list_item`

In your main activity, you already add the string you want to the adapter. So in the adapter, split the string and assign the name to one textView and the rest of the string to the other.

```
String[] data = childText.split("\n");

String name = data[0];
String restOfInfo = data[1] + "\n" + data[2];
```